# Python: How to pass parameters when it isn't an option?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, partial

I have a function - func_main - which has several inputs. One of the inputs is another function - func_mini. The smaller function, func_mini, loads some data, and it needs to be able to load data from different sources depending on the arguments passed to it. The issue is that I am reading the documentation on func_main and it says that it only accepts parameterless functions. How can I get around this?

For example:

```
def func_main(evaluator = None):

    num_list = [1,2,3]
    return evaluator(num_list)  



def func_mini(data_source = None):

    if not data_source:
        data_source = config.DATA_SOURCE

    return pandas.read_csv(data_source).min
```

I want do to this:

```
func_main(func_mini(data_souce='path/to/my/file'))
```

But func_main documentation says:

"evaluator: A parameterless function that defines and return all data needed in the above model definition."

Comment: So you want to create a dynamic function then, that's bound to some parameter values you create?

Comment: Yes, I think timgeb hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial` to build a function without parameters from your original `func_mini` function. Demo:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def foo(x):
...     print(x)
... 
>>> foo_argless = partial(foo, 'hi')
>>> foo_argless()
hi
```